# Google Drive service account has become read only The file is view-only No edits can be made to this file

Tags: google-sheets, google-drive-api

The Google Dive for the service account has become read only
I wrote a script to delete files and that is working but cannot create new google sheets.

When create I get Error from API :
Resource has been exhausted (e.g. check quota).] Location[ - ] Reason[rateLimitExceeded] Domain[global]

And if you view an old sheet you get
The file is view-only No edits can be made to this file. Contact file owner for details.

Deleteing files works

```
var del = oGooleDive.driveService.Files.Delete(file.Id);
await del.ExecuteAsync();
```

But create does not

```
Spreadsheet newSheet = new Spreadsheet();
SpreadsheetProperties properties = new SpreadsheetProperties();
properties.Title = ClientName + " " + DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss tt");
newSheet.Properties = properties;
var c = service.Spreadsheets.Create(newSheet);
```

Answer (score 1):

I am going to take a guess here. If its not corect then i will delete this.

The way service accounts work is that they are their own dummy user.  So a service account has its own google drive account.

If you do an [about.get](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/about/get) from the service account. You will be able to see how much space it has.

So what is causing your error.

Well rateLimitExceeded would imply that you are going to fast.  That you have created two many files at once,  but for this to happen i would guess you have probably created 100 files within a minute or so.

Im going to take a guess and say that Resource has been exhausted means that your service account has run out of space.  You cant create any more files because there's no space left.

There is no way to add additional space to a service account.